# Как в Spring можно принимать сообщения?

Tags: spring, java, email

Здравствуйте!Интересует вопрос каким образом можно принимать сообщения (например с Gmail) в Spring. Именно спринговые либы, а не javax.mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Священное писание](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html) учит нас, что спринг "из коробки" может отправлять почту (причем поверх все того же JavaMail), но не принимать ее.

Хотя если очень хочется, то можно прикрутить, например, Apache Camel, забирать им почту и слать в Spring, через JMS. Но надо ли оно вам?